# Twitter bootstrap typeahead 2.1.1 can't set function in source

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to set the source into the bootstrap typeahead, but I'm getting the following error:

```
typeahead.process is not a function
```

Here's a jsFiddle illustrating the case: http://jsfiddle.net/NCEFR/1/

What am I doing improperly?

Notice the version of the plugin is 2.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the typeahead doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)

> The function is passed two arguments, the `query` value in the input field and the `process` callback. The function may be used synchronously by returning the data source directly or asynchronously via the `process` callback's single argument.

Correct function arguments :

```js
var searchFunction = function(query, process) {  
    var result = "result1::result2".split("::");
    process(result);
}
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/NCEFR/4/)